# How to specify response time in logback access logs for jetty?

Tags: jetty, logback, access-log

I see that you can enable viewing response time for a given HTTP request in Jetty using NCSARequestLog by setting "logLatency" to true or setLogLatency(true). How can this be done via logback implementation(ch.qos.logback.access.jetty.RequestLogImpl) ?

Thanks in advance for answering!